# Commander not using default values

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, argv, node-commander

I setup commander with defaultArgs like this:

```
import * as validations from './validation'
import program from 'commander'
import path from 'path'

export default function initializeCommander (defaults) {
  program
    .version('0.0.1')
    .usage('redbubble-demo')
    .option('-u', '--url [url]', validations.isValidUrl, defaults.url)
    .option('-o', '--output-dir [path]', validations.hasValidParentDirectory, path.resolve(defaults.path))
    .option('-s', '--size [size]', validations.isValidSize, defaults.size)
    .parse(process.argv)

  return program
}
```

I have the default values set up here and pass them to the function like this:

```
const defaultValues = {
  url: 'someuRL',
  size: 'medium',
  outputDir: './www'
}
const program = initializeCommander(defaultValues)
console.log(program) //no value in console
```

When I try and access the options from `program`, i get no values.

I call my app without any arguments using:

```
babel-node src/index.js
```

## UPDATE:

I am able to run the app as a binary now using `npm link` but i get this error:

```
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.resolve (path.js:1146:7)
    at initializeCommander (/home/vamsi/Do/redbubble-demo/build/index.js:9889:222)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vamsi/Do/redbubble-demo/build/index.js:87:34)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/vamsi/Do/redbubble-demo/build/index.js:22:30)
    at /home/vamsi/Do/redbubble-demo/build/index.js:42:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vamsi/Do/redbubble-demo/build/index.js:45:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
```

The line numbers in the `stack trace` are off because I am using `webpack` to bundle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I'm curious as to why you are using webpack to bundle a Node cli. Traditionally bundlers like webpack or browserify are used to replicate the node module system for client side projects, not for server side ones.</strike> (Today I learned that this is a JSPM/babel-node alternative.)

Commander is throwing an exception because your default is called `outputDir` not `path` but you are passing `path.resolve(defaults.path))` in your commander definition.

Comment: I am using webpack because I have `import` statements all over my code. Also, I read http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I . It does not process the long args such as `--output-dir` but works correctly with `-o`. How can I get to process the long args as well?